# Textposition got in PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am now using PDFBox to get the textposition of one character using TextPosition.getX() and TextPosition.getY().
But I am not sure whether the coordinate returned is the upper left or the bottom left of the character.
What i want is the upper left and the bottom right coordinate of the character.

Thanks.

Comment: It's neither top nor bottom, its on the base line.

Comment: This code comes close to what you need: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.java?view=markup

Comment: What do you mean by base line?
Is it the center of the text?@mkl

Comment: No, [the baseline is the line upon which most letters "sit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)), also see this [example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Typography_Line_Terms.svg).